# Should git fetch point to heroku or my alias

Tags: git, heroku

I have this in my `.git/config` (fetch points to dev)

```
[remote "dev"]
  url = git@heroku.com:site-dev.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dev/*
```

And my coworker has this (fetch points to `heroku`)

```
[remote "dev"]
  url = git@heroku.com:site-dev.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

And they both seem to work. How could that be?  The fetch perimeter for his is the same for dev, staging, and production.  Where are we each actually fetching from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 pieces of information there.

This is the remote alias.

```
[ remote "dev"]
```

In the repository where that config entry exists that is available to the commands `git remote`, `git fetch`, and `git push`.  A local repository can use any alias it wants to refer to any repository.  The whole point of the alias is to save you from having to type the longer URL each time.

The URL is the location and communication protocol to find a particular aliased repository.

```
url = git@heroku.com:site-dev.git
```

So in your sample `git push dev` would translate to `git push git@heroku.com:site-dev.git`

Lastly you have the fetch specification

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dev/*
```

The part before the colon says "what references am I fetching from the remote", and the part after the colon says "how am I going to refer to those references locally".  Typically you would have your local refs match the remote alias (as you do, but your coworker does not) because it's easier to think about that way, but there is no requirement for that.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. So it looks like I can leave mine as is, right?  What do you think about the fact that the coworker has heroku as the "how I'm going to refer to these references locally" in three different situations- dev, staging, and production.  Wouldn't that cause problems?

Comment: are you saying he has 3 remotes in a single repostory/.git/config, or that he has 3 repositories, and each of them have 1 remote that is aliased differently?

Comment: We have one repository. So I believe that would be 3 remotes in a single repository/.git/config.

Comment: I have the following in my config:
    [branch "master"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/master
    [branch "develop"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/develop
    [remote "staging"]
     url =  git@heroku.com:site-staging.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
    [remote "dev"]
     url = git@heroku.com:site-dev.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dev/*
    [remote "prod"]
     url = git@heroku.com:site-prod.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/prod/*

Comment: If you are saying he has 3 separate remotes pointing to 3 different git repositories, but the "fetch" line is the same for them then your coworker will have problems.

Comment: it's only 1 git repository.   I think we have a pretty standard set up for we have one git repository and three deployment environments… develop, staging, production.